# Regular expression to allow from 0 to 365 with decimals but 365 should have all decimal digit as 0 only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a Regular expression to allow from 0 to 365 with optional decimals but 365 should have all optional decimal digit as 0 only.

```
^(0?[0-9]?[0-9]|[1-2][0-9][0-9]|3[0-5][0-9])(\.\d+)|(36[0-5])(\.[0]+)?$
```

This is accepting only 365 and 365 followed by decimals like (365.0,365.00) but its accepting only with decimal  1.0, 10.0,100.0 and not without decimal 1,10,100 not sure what's happening. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `(?:[12]?\d{1,2}|3[0-5]\d|36[0-4])(?:\.\d+)?|365(?:\.0+)?`

Comment: The proper answer would be: match all possible digits and compare them programatically. Although possible with regular expressions, this is likely not maintenable and you'll certainly forget the meaning in a couple of weeks.

Comment: It seems like a regex is the wrong solution here, where and why do you need this regex? Why not just use something like `Number.isNaN(Number.parseFloat(value)) && value < 365`, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/nB9xPL/1/))

```
^(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3[0-5]\d|36[0-4]|365\.0*)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Or (better !):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

and compare the values programmatically afterwards.
The latter could be:

```js
let data = `0.00
123.2121212
365.00
365.11
-1000
299
1000
365.1`;

let regex = /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/gm;
while (found = regex.exec(data)) {
    number = parseFloat(found[0]);
    if (number >= 0 && number <= 365) {
        console.log(number + " (" + found[0] + ")");
    }
}
```